# Как такое реализовать на canvase?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Нужно чтобы карта была в целом 1000на1000, но ВИДНАЯ часть лишь 100на100, как это сделать? Можно ли как-то указать координаты начала ВИДИМОГО экрана и его конец.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зная размеры и положение окна, определи тайлы, которые в него попадают, отрисуй их целиком, а потом сдвинь чутка до нужного положения.

Comment: аналогичный вопрос с решением в английском SO [Draw tilemap only on visible canvas area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710562/draw-tilemap-only-on-visible-canvas-area-optimization)

Comment: Совсем другая тема вопроса, Lexx918

Answer (score 6):

```js
let cameraWidth = 100;
let cameraHeight = 100;
let camera = document.getElementById("camera");
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  // Motion
  camera.style.left = e.clientX - cameraWidth / 2 + "px";
  camera.style.top = e.clientY - cameraHeight / 2 + "px";
  canvas.style.left = -e.clientX + "px";
  canvas.style.top = -e.clientY + "px";
});
```

```css
#camera {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 240px;
  background: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdigitalfellows.commons.gc.cuny.edu%2Ffiles%2F2015%2F03%2Fgithub_logo-1.png&f=1&nofb=1) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="camera">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем случае это больше на хак похоже и к канвасу отношения не имеет)

Comment: @ThisMan не совсем понял в чем проблема?

Comment: мне понравилсья лови плюс

Answer (score 3):

Набросал на коленке решение. Создаю огромную карту тайлов 200 на 200. Генерю в каждый тайл случайный цвет, но с градиентом на всю карту, чтоб было заметно как окно движется над картой. Затем запускаю над картой окно по кругу против часовой стрелки начиная с правого края карты. Рендерятся только видимые тайлы. Может где ошибся и есть погрешности округления, но думаю можно меня простить :) Главное, что суть понятна.

```js
Math.rad = function(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
};

let tilesTotalX = 200,
    tilesTotalY = 200,
    tilesVisibleX = 10,
    tilesVisibleY = 7,
    tileWidth = 20,
    tileHeight = 20;

let worldSize = {
    w: tilesTotalX * tileWidth,
    h: tilesTotalY * tileHeight
};

let windowSize = {
    w: tilesVisibleX * tileWidth,
    h: tilesVisibleY * tileHeight
};

let tiles = [];
for (let row = 0; row < tilesTotalY; row++) {
    tiles.push([]);
    for (let col = 0; col < tilesTotalX; col++) {
        let r = (Math.floor(0xFF * (row / tilesTotalY))).toString(16),
            g = (Math.floor(0xFF * (col / tilesTotalX))).toString(16),
            b = (Math.floor(0xFF * Math.random())).toString(16);
        tiles[row].push(`#${r}${g}${b}`);
    }
}

let angle = 0,
step = .3;

let circle = {
    x: Math.round((worldSize.w - windowSize.w) / 2),
    y: Math.round((worldSize.h - windowSize.h) / 2),
    r: Math.round(((worldSize.h - windowSize.h) / 2) * .8),
};

let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#f0f0f0";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, windowSize.w, windowSize.h);

let fps = 16,
    fpsInterval = 1000 / fps,
    then = Date.now();

(function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    let now = Date.now(),
        elapsed = now - then;
    if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
        then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);

        angle += step;
        angle %= 360;
        //console.log(angle);

        let windowPosition = {
            x: Math.round(circle.x + Math.cos(Math.rad(angle)) * circle.r),
            y: Math.round(circle.y - Math.sin(Math.rad(angle)) * circle.r)
        };

        let firstVisibleRowIndex = Math.floor(windowPosition.y / tileHeight),
            firstVisibleColIndex = Math.floor(windowPosition.x / tileWidth),
            lastVisibleRowIndex = Math.floor((windowPosition.y + windowSize.h) / tileHeight),
            lastVisibleColIndex = Math.floor((windowPosition.x + windowSize.w) / tileWidth);

        let offset = {
            x: windowPosition.x - tileWidth * Math.floor(windowPosition.x / tileWidth),
            y: windowPosition.y - tileHeight * Math.floor(windowPosition.y / tileHeight)
        };

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(-offset.x, -offset.y);
        for (let row = firstVisibleRowIndex; row <= lastVisibleRowIndex; row++) {
            for (let col = firstVisibleColIndex; col <= lastVisibleColIndex; col++) {
                ctx.fillStyle = tiles[row][col];
                ctx.fillRect(
                    tileWidth * (col - firstVisibleColIndex),
                    tileHeight * (row - firstVisibleRowIndex),
                    tileWidth,
                    tileHeight
                );
            }
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
})();
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=200 height=140></canvas>
```

Comment: Lexx918, спасибо большое за ваше старание. Но, к сожалению я новичок и больше половины не понял. То есть для якобы "камеры", нужно добавлять на холст отдельный элемент через fillRect и размер этого элемента равен той части, которую нужно выводить на ВИДИМЫЙ экран?

Comment: Мне нужно лишь понять как сделать и отображать только видимую часть экрана и можно было позиционировать её через координаты, а дальше я сам разберусь. Можете помочь пожалуйста? Потому что у меня сразу весь canvas выводится на экран. Например, создаю холст: <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"> и вот у меня сразу 500х500 выводится, а мне нужно чтобы видно было лишь 100х100, а остальная область была скрыта.

Comment: @Holter для ответа надо больше входных данных. откуда у вас данных для 500x500? можно ли вынуть только 100 на 100? если да, то просто их отрисуйте. если нет, то почему нельзя? холст у вас будет точно всегда 100 на 100. осталось понять как корректно вынуть данные для него. возможно это вообще вопрос не про рендер, а про получение данных из источника. пока по вопросу не понятно.

Comment: Опишу более детально цель. Имеется холст, его размер 500х500: <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500">.  При загрузке страницы холст отображается целиком 500x500, НО мне нужно чтобы отображалось часть этого холста 100х100. Вот вопрос: как мне создать эту "камеру" с размером 100х100?

Comment: В Вашем ответе на вопрос Вы сделали систему такую как нужна. Но там ещё есть движение этой самой камеры, генерация тайлов, вот в этом я запутался и не знаю где конкретно часть кода, отвечающая за создание камеры.